# What are the HTML attributes expecting a date/time value?

Tags: html, attributes, w3c

I've been looking for a place that list all of the official HTML attributes that expect a ["date/time"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#dates-and-times) kind of value, other than `datetime`

I've found [this GitHub](https://github.com/iandevlin/html-attributes) listing all boolean attributes and enumerated attributes. I'm looking for a list of all attributes, separated by type of expected value.

Comment: If you feel like downvoting this, fine but leave a comment about why it’s not the place or why the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I've kept on searching and finaly found exactly what I was looking for, [a full list of attributes and their expected value types!](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3)

Also, the `datetime` is indeed the only attribute expecting any kind of date/time value.